What is the best chart or infographics to present a Confidence Index Ranking?
Let's say there is some Confidence Ranking - i.e. Consumer Confidence Ranking.



Year
Rank




2010
1


2011
2


2012
2


2013
5


2014
7


2015
8



The rank is going down - i.e consumer confidence is going down - i.e. it's bad.
If I make a chart from this, it would look like this.

But in general, going up in a chart gives the perception of something good happening.
Is there a better way (other than labelling etc) to present this infographic?

I don't know if this is against best practices, but if you flip the graph, with the x-axis on top and the y-axis reversed, that might solve the problem.

What is a Confidence Index Ranking? Is it a nominal, ordinal or quantitative kind of data? It seems to be purely ordinal: twice the rank means nothing. In that case, an xy graph with lines is not ideal (even wrong).

@PabloH - let's say you have 10 countries & you are ranking consumer confidence on the economy in those 10 countries.  Consumers from the country with rank 1 has the better confidence in their economy than the remaining 9 & so on. So yes, twice the rank means nothing. What is the right type of chart or infographic to depict this?

@minseong I never knew this was an option. Just discovered that even excel has a way to do this, so I am guessing it must be an accepted way

Another idea is to invert the Y-axis. Keep the same line chart but invert the y-axis, so 1 is at the top and 10 is at the bottom. This way, the line will trend downward, matching the declining confidence.


Reading from top to bottom might confuse people. Placing the X-axis on top could solve this.

Yes I agree. I prefer the Using score instead of rank answer tbh. But not sure if its feasible for the situation of the questioner.


Using score instead of rank.

Now, how to calculate the score?. Track back on how did you calculate the rank. It might be based on a few metrics. So you may use that metric to plot the score chart directly instead of rank.
If there was no metrics involved during ranking, do an inverse on the rank. You can see the fx in the image attached to see what I did.


Chart of increasing risk
Googling brings up examples of representation, most with color enhancement. A summary:
Background increasing risk color

Increasing risk shape

Background increasing risk gradient

Increasing risk graph color

Increasing risk comparison level
Dividing the chart between "normal" and risky levels:

